# Accessing the PFUser currentUser from an iOS8 Today Widget

Tags: parse-platform, ios8, ios-app-extension

I asked this question in the Parse google group, but figured I'd open it up wider here on SO.  I'm still a little fuzzy around the rules surrounding discussing anything related to iOS8 prior to the official release, but with GM out and extensions discussed, I figure I can ask this question now.  If not, it can wait.

I'm using Parse for the backend.  I'd like to build a Today widget that displays a few records related to a specific currentUser.  Loading and initializing Parse isn't the issue, framework is loaded and initialized, that is fine.  But even when logged into the container app, it appears I have no reference to the currentUser.

This is the code I created just to confirm I could get access to the current user, which does not work.  I attempted to save it in NSUserDefault, which is probably a hack anyway, but was unsuccessful.

```
 PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (currentUser) { 
        nameTF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [currentUser objectForKey:@"firstName"], [currentUser objectForKey:@"lastName"]]; 
    } else { 
        nameTF.text = @"No freaking clue who you are."; 
    }
```

But all I see is the "no freaking clue ..." text.

My first question is whether or not I can access the current user? I assume I can and need to somehow get it in the group and I'm missing something silly.  And if so, can someone point me to a source or information on the best way to accomplish this?  Once I can make queries with the current User I'll be fine.

Thanks again for any suggestions you can offer.

*** UPDATE ***

After a suggestion from Fosco Marotto at Parse to store the sessionToken in NSUserDefaults and then use that token within the extension to call PFUser becomeInBackground, I put the following code together to test the suggestion and this works.  It needs to be improved on because it is a bit hackish, so I'm not marking it as the answer.

```
NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]   initWithSuiteName:@"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]; 
NSString *pfToken = [sharedDefaults valueForKey:@"PFUserSessionToken"]; 

[PFUser becomeInBackground:pfToken block:^(PFUser *currentUser, NSError *error) { 
   if (error) { 
      // The token could not be validated. 
      NSLog(@"error happened during becomeInBackground - token could not be validated"); 
      // Show the token just to make sure we got it
      nameTF.text = pfToken; 
   } else { 
      // The current user is now set to user. 
      // do stuff with the user 
      nameTF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [currentUser objectForKey:@"firstName"], [currentUser objectForKey:@"lastName"]]; 
   } 
}];

// Now lets see if we can get PFUser outside of the block

// Not sure if we need this

PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

if (currentUser) {
     // We have a reference to currentUser
     nameTF.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [currentUser objectForKey:@"firstName"]];
} else {

    nameTF.text = @"Don't think you're getting the PFUser thing right here";
}
```

I can get the currentUser and query against it.  Thanks to Fosco for the direction and hopefully this is getting closer to a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now Parse offers official solution for sharing data between host app and extension. More info can be found at https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#extensions

Answer (score -1):

I was successful in saving an NSString of the current user's username from my app to the user defaults.  Then in the widget's view controller, I queried for the user with that username.

Comment: I'm not sure this solution will give the full access we need.  Fosco @ Parse gave this untested suggestion over in the Parse Google Group "Apple has some information here that points to the workaround:  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Have not attempted it yet, but the idea would be to store the PFUser sessionToken in NSUserDefaults, and when the extension is activated, grab that sessionToken and use the PFUser becomeInBackground functionality."

I've tested it and it works.